# Adding code to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have recently being using XAMPP and phpMyAdmin to create databases. I have php scripts to update and read from the database and thats all good. Now i want to serverdatabase to perform some calculations in the background and update the relevant columns. MySQL allows for code scripting to be performed on the database.

However the database created in XAMPP is not accessible in MYSQL workbench even though XAMPP has MySQL embedded in it.

So what is the best way to add the coding functionality. Would it be to create it from scratch in MySQL and then connect to it in phpMyAdmin or would there be a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: take the sql from workbench and go to the phpmyadmin.You will notice that you have a button called "sql" paste that sql and it will work...

Comment: Either go with @Arslan.H solution or configure MySQL to allow connections from different clients.

Comment: @Arslan.H I can use the sql tab to perform queries on the database but this must be done manually. I would like this to be done automatically in the background periodically every couple of minutes or whenever the table has been updated. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it can.Crone jobs are used for that or you can use Scheduled Events also for it.

Comment: Cool. Is there any documentation or useful links you could direct me to? Can the same be done using windows?

Comment: So it turns out that the triggering events are a bit limited (and temperamental) and will not suffice if I want something running continuously in the background. I might have to develop some sort of database controlling software in C or Java that will effectively be the brains of the operation. Would this be typical and what would be the best practices?

Comment: You are falling out of the path there....I won't say anything go with that approach and you will see the problems that you will have.Sometimes it's better to learn on own mistakes